# How to create and use DLL modules in C#? Not DLL assembles

Tags: c#, dll

I want to create an application that using DLL modules that dynamically connects to application. For example: create a special folder with DLL modules, user can add new modules, program at startup scan this folder and connect it. So I cannot compile like 
csc /out:TestCode.exe /reference:MathLibrary.DLL TestCode.cs
because I have not DLL name. There will be many DLL's with definetly structure: Load(), Free(), Settings(), Name() and so on.

Also i want to know, is there an function with name XXX in this DLL (for optional functions, ex. Settings() may exist and may not).

Language: C# for application and DLL.

Like a plugins in application. In C this is easy.

Comment: Try [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) or you can write your own Plugin System for you app. [Link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4691/Plugin-Architecture-using-C)

Comment: Thanks. I think there is another type of DLL in C#. So i must just use Reflection. So it will have too much code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/).